# php variables on google chart

Tags: php, variables, charts

i have google charts working but need to pass the variables to its javascript builder, i tried to use $var inside javascript but it dont work.......

i have :

```
    script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
          google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Estrelas', 'Pontuação'],
              ['1 estrelas',     $ums],
              ['2 estrelas',      $doiss],
              ['3 estrelas',  $tress],
              ['3 estrelas', $quatros],
              ['5 estrela',    $cincos]
            ]);

            var options = {
              title: 'My Daily Activities'
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
          }
        </script>
```

Comment: there are at least 4 duplicated of this question alreadys :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to encapsulate the PHP vars, like:

```
['1 estrelas',     <? echo $ums?> ],
```

or if your PHP config accepts short tags

```
['1 estrelas',     <?= $ums ?> ],
```

Comment: tks it worked fine

Comment: Since PHP 5.4 and up, you can use `<?=` regardless of the short tag setting, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 0):

Try putting PHP tags around it, for example:
`['1 estrelas',     $ums]` becomes `['1 estrelas',     <?php echo $ums; ?>]`,

Comment: tks it worked fine